# Does MS C# Implementation of String check ReferenceEquals of the immuteable base String first?

Tags: c#, string

Suppose i had some `String`s.

```
String a = "this String";
Strinb b = "this String";
String c = a;
```

As i understand string `a` and `b` do not nescessarily share the same immuteable base string. But String `c` is a copy of `a`, so it points internally to the same immuteable string.

If i compare `a` and `b` for equality, it will return true. At least because they represent the same character sequence.

If i compare `a` and `c` for equality, it will return true. Did it check the characters to do so or did it compare the pointers to the immuteable string first?

---

Edit:

To answer how i would check equality:

```
    private void StackoverflowEquals()
    {
        String a = @"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932695/does-ms-c-sharp-implementation-of-string-check-referenceequals-of-the-immuteable";
        String b = @"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932695/does-ms-c-sharp-implementation-of-string-check-referenceequals-of-the-immuteable";
        String c = a;

        if (!(a == b)) throw new Exception();
        if (!(a == c)) throw new Exception();
    }
```

Comment: How did you check their equality?

Comment: Sure, [first thing it does](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#603).  Checking for Length equality is next, that's very cheap too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. Here's the source code for equals:

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
        public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == null)                        //this is necessary to guard against reverse-pinvokes and
                throw new NullReferenceException();  //other callers who do not use the callvirt instruction

            String str = obj as String;
            if (str == null)
                return false;

            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
                return true;

            if (this.Length != str.Length)
                return false;

            return EqualsHelper(this, str);
        }
```

For complete string class source code see [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs).